# Migrating to .Net 4: Null reference exceptions thrown when adding event in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-4.0

At my place of work we've recently been upgrading our codebase from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4 (C#). Most issues encountered have been solved however this one I can't figure out. We initialise controls and pages through a mix of xaml and code behind (based on developer preference), however one page is throwing *NullReferenceException* when opened. Here is a snippet of code that is (one of many controls) throwing.

**All the code throwing exceptions is inside a DataTemplate** (*I figured that might be relevant*)

```
<TextBox x:Name="Values" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,2,5,2"
  Text="{Binding ElementName=Descriptions, Path=SelectedValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
  Mode=TwoWay,        
  Converter={StaticResource EmptyConverter}}"
  GotFocus="Column_GotFocus"
  MinWidth="100"
  CharacterCasing="Upper"
  Visibility="{Binding Path=IsValueVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" 
/>
```

Now in this, the line throwing is:

```
GotFocus="Column_GotFocus"
```

Column_GotFocus is in the code behind file.
A few more facts: we had no issues before the migration, the exception gets throws continuously, and there are three different events causing this issue.

The three events throwing are:

```
GotFocus="Column_GotFocus"
SelectionChanged="Descriptions_SelectionChanged"
Click="Search_Click"
```

Removing these fixes our problem completely, but obviously causes functional problems with the software. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing these issues?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, to clarify: The event handler is never called, the xaml event handler adding (GotFocus="Column_GotFocus" for example) seems to be where the exception is thrown.

The exception is:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source= <assembly/namespace>
  StackTrace:
       at <assembly/namespace>.<Class>.System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector.Connect(Int32 connectionId, Object target) in <XamlFilePath>:line 291
  InnerException:
```

**Edit 2:**

The method handler is:

```
    private void Column_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentPresenter columnContentPresenter =(DependencyObject)sender).FindParent<ContentPresenter>();

        Column column = (Column)columnContentPresenter.Content;

        string message = string.Format("{0} ({1})", column.Name, column.Field);

        ModuleDescriptor.UpdateStatusBar(message);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger to the Visual Studio process you are attempting to open the designer in? This involves a second instance of VS running. Also, instead of removing the events, have you tried adding any tracing code to the event handlers to check every possible instance for being null? It'll at least allow you to throw a better exception. I suspect there is simply a null inside one of the handlers, and has nothing to do with the events themselves. My other suspicion is data binding, but it appears you've bound to the code behind.

Comment: I don't see a single line of C# code. If you want help you need to provide the C# code connected to this event, post the exact exception, and show us you have actually attempted to debug the problem yourself.  Once you post the C# code connected to this I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound C# code aside, it is clearly evident the OP has tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - I don't get the same impression. When I see C# code and the exception posted, I will remove the downvote, it will remain until that happens. I won't have this offtopic discussion in the comments.  Its clear the user has not used the debugger, because they don't know which object is a null reference exception, that one of the basic steps of attempting to debug the problem yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have tried to solve my problem (several days + several other team members). I will happily add the exception and c# code. I just didn't want to give pages and pages of possibly redundant info, this is my first stackoverflow contribution so I'm still learning how to best ask a question. What C# code do you think I should add? The constructor, event handler...etc.

Comment: @Ramhound With the VS designer it is not necessarily basic, sometimes people just don't think that the designer can be debugged. I don't disagree that the code should be posted, just your blanket statement about the OP not doing enough to show they are working on it. Just because they didn't happen to provide enough isn't evidence that they aren't bothering to work on it.

Comment: @JamieWroe The event handler code should be enough.

Comment: Well, I've edited the question. I'll add the event handler code if you think it will help, I didn't think it could be causing this issue which is why I left it off. I also had no idea you could debug the designer, so thanks for that :) Back on topic, what is the reasoning behind debugging the designer in this situation if you don't mind?

Comment: @JamieWroe I mentioned it because I first thought this was when you opened the page in the designer, but I now see that I probably made that bit up :-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth No worries, I realise now it was vague. I guess it's a bit hard at times to know if something's clear enough to the reader!

Comment: Post the code that is connected to `IStyleConnector.Connect` the reference to the object is null.

Comment: @Ramhound Any advice on how to do that? With the IStyleConnector being a xaml parser interface I'm not sure how I can 'see' the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think th problem is you are trying to add event handlers while you are in a style setter.
This is forbidden (for obscure reasons)...
You should use EventSetters instead

For example:

```
<Style x:Key="YourSyleName" TargetType="{x:Type CtrlType}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="dgClient_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="GridContent_Loaded"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ah I see, thanks I'll look into that now. Is this something that has changed in .Net 4 though? Before our migration this code was working fine.

Comment: @JamieWroe - If I were to hazard a guess it actually was a problem before but was being eaten for some reason, now that something else has change, it is an actual problem now.

Comment: @Kek, I've looked into EventTriggers, are they not limited to xaml in what they can do? Is there a way to wire up a method to a function using EventTriggers or will I just have to rewrite large swaths of the page using bindings and dependency properties?

Comment: Well, as I wrote above, "it's quite a pain to code" :( There are ways, but I don't remember.. let me 5 min

Comment: My memory is quite in a bad state... We are talking about EventSetters. I updated the answer

Comment: Ha, well I'm not complaining :) - I'll try this and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I would never have thought this old piece of code would be reused some day :)

Answer (score 10):

This is a framework bug and it is already fixed, please download the hot fix to overcome the issue!!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2464222

Bug report is here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/629bfcc5-2005-4947-a001-993524798b52

Download the file here